# Sterio Mix in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: sound, wine, skype, microphone

I've been wondering if in Ubuntu, I can "spoof" another microphone that is actually the Speakers and the Microphone fused together. My audio card supports this. What I mean is, for example, If i'm on a Skype call, since I usually wear headphones, I want them to be able to hear what my PC speakers are outputting and what my microphone is picking up. That way, I can get together with a friend and watch Netflix (Using Wine) or play a game and have him hear the audio. This can also be useful in other scenarios. In Windows, this is referred to as "Sterio Mix"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Launch PulseAudio Volume Control (from the dash or a terminal):

```
pavucontrol
```

On Input devices tab, see that you have "Monitor of Built-in Analog Stereo"
this is a virtual recording device with which you can record whatever's coming out of your speakers.

[image]

Now we just need to route your microphone to your speakers too.
Do this by typing the following command in a terminal:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

If you now record with `audacity`, or `recordmydesktop`, from the "Monitor of Built-in Analogy Stereo" (see Recording tab of pavucontrol after you start recording)
you'll get your microphone as well as whatever's coming out of the speakers.

This means that you can now easily record Skype meetings or private Google+ Hangouts.

Comment: 3 Questions: 1.Will this work if I wear headphones 2.I have a TV Tuner installed and apparantly Ubuntu detects it as a sterio 3.Do I have to reboot?

Comment: 1. It will work, the loopback is internal (does not depend on speakers or heasets), 2. It inactive, it won't get captured, 3. No, don't reboot otherwise the pulseaudio loopback will be deleted. It will last only the time of your session.

Comment: Your welcome! And since just that wouldn't fit in the character limit, I had to add this sentance.